# Selecting glyphs of font based on previous and next char, aka "continuous ligatures"

Tags: fonts, font-design, glyphs, opentype, ligatures

I'm currently thinking of designing a new font prototype, whose specificity is to adapt each glyph based on the previous **and** next character.

The idea is to split each glyph in **two parts**, "left" and "right"; with optionally various versions for each. Composition would then select the *left* part based on the *previous* character, and the *right* based on the *next*. The final glyph would be the union of both parts.

For example, for buiding the letter **a** on some font:

- **Pan** would use a left version having a slightly shortened top arm  (this version to use with v, y...); and a right version with a straight final (downright) stroke (to use with letters i, n, h...)
- **bao** would use a left version having a normal top arm (this version to use with lots of letters); and a right version with a standard curvy final stroke (to use with o, d, e, p...)

[image: Example for the letter a of continuous ligaturing using Linux Libertine as a base font]

In this example, the lowercase **a** would have 3 left versions (short / normal / long top arm), and 2 right versions (curvy / straight downright final stroke), so in total 6 glyph versions.

Standard ligatures (ff, fi, ffl...) would be implicitly built by selecting the appropriate right/left version pair.

I would call this concept *"continuous ligaturing"*.

My question is thus two-fold:

- Does this concept already exists?
- Does some font format (OpenType?) allow for the selection of a specific glyph version based on previous and next character? I could eventually pre-process the font by creating for each glyph with N lefts and M rights a N×M matrix of all possible combinations (N and M are usually rather low, often 1 or 2, sometimes 3, 4 or 5).